# How to change the frame_id from recorded bag files [bag_tools don't work]

Tags: ros, rosbag, frame-id, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I need to change the frame_id of my `imu/data` topic from `/base_imu` to `base_imu`.
I'm using Indigo.
Unfortunately, I recorded several bag files without removing the slash character now I can't run them since I always get  this error message:

```
Warning: Invalid argument "/base_imu" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like: 
         at line 130 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-tf2-0.5.15/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

I know that I can use [bag_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/bag_tools?distro=indigo), but they do not work: if I try to install them from apt-get the package "`change_frame_id`" is not found, if I try to install them from source, catkin_make fails and do not build the package.

Is there any other way to change the frame_id?
Can you help me, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285005/how-to-change-the-frame_id-from-recorded-bag-files-%5Bbag_tools-don%27t-work%5D/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2018-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by copying the `change_frame_id.py` file inside the bag_tools folder located in `/opt/ros/indigo/share/bag_tools`.

Now it works.

I think the ros node installed by `apt-get` does not copy all the files inside the ros directory.

I opened a new issue on: https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/issues/19

---

Originally posted by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) with karma: 287 on 2018-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-11**:\

> I think the ros node installed by `apt-get` does not copy all the files inside the ros directory.

have you reported this over at [srv/srv_tools/issues](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/issues)?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-11**:
I did it few minutes ago

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-12**:
And the link to the issue?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-12**:
You can find it in "Issues" on "srv_tools" github.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-12**:
Obviously, but as a service to future readers it would be nice if you can post the link here.

Also: if your issue gets closed/resolved, it would not be immediately clear to which issue you are referring.

That way we keep things connected.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2018-03-12**:
I edited the answer by adding the link to the issue.